# "Automatic" VS "Autonomous"

Tags: word-usage

1. ***Automatic*** adaptation of the speed by the frequency converter also compensates for a possible drop in performance due to wear on spindles or impellers.
2. ***Autonomous*** adaptation of the speed by the frequency converter also compensates for a possible drop in performance due to wear on spindles or impellers.

Are Automatic and Autonomous exchangable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic and Autonomous could be seen as almost having **opposite** meanings.

Automatic has the flavour of pre-programmed action. One dictionary definition:

> (of a device or process) working by itself with little or no direct
>   human control. "an automatic kettle that switches itself off when it
>   boils"

Autonomy implies a freedom to make decisions

> having the freedom to act independently. "school governors are legally
>   autonomous"

So we can view Automatic as implying pre-determination and Autonomous as implying freedom of choice.

However, humans have an autonomous nervous system that controls things such as rate of breathing and heartbeat. It's not under our conscious control, and makes quite complex decisions. So if your control mechanism were sufficiently complex it could be viewed as autonomous in this sense - I was employed by a company that was very proud of it's self-regulating software, and dubbed it autonomous.

I think you probably should use automatic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that they are not exchangeable. Which one to use depends on what you are trying to say.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**automatic**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/automatic)

> An automatic machine or device is **able to operate independently of human** control

[**autonomous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/autonomous)

> **independent and having the power** to make your own decisions

The difference between them is subtle. Usually the first one is used to remark that **is able to operate independently of human control** and the second when the device got its **own supply of power**, a separate battery or connection that is independent from the main battery of the whole machine. Your question is getting close votes because it's centered in a specific field of knowledge, maybe you should ask in a specialized forum of engineers.

Comment: "having the power" here I think means self-determination rather than source of energy

Comment: @djna I know that but I'm no expert in the terminology used in Engineering in English. Do you know the term used in that field for the concept that I described? No irony there.